# make click event and remove overlap of circle in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

I write this html and javascript code :

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjjq5/)**

when you click on a coordinate of canvas , draw a circle .
now I want do this two action in code :

**1** - Create click event , that when I click on circle , open the below bootstrap dropdown menu:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
    Dropdown
    <b class="caret"></b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

**2** - User can't draw 2 circle that the circle have overlap .

Comment: *What have you tried?*

Comment: To do this you are going to need to track the original mouse position for the click and store the position. Then you will need to check to see if that position falls inside of another mouse clicks circle. If it does then instead of drawing a new circle to the canvas show the menu. if it doesnt then draw a new circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your script to do what you want. You will probably need to update it further. Basically you need to store the mouse click events and add menus as you create new circles. then all new clicks get checked and if they are in the circle they display the menu if they are too close an alert happens and if they are far enough away a new circle is drawn.

http://jsfiddle.net/sjjq5/1/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var canvasOffset = $("#myCanvas").offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var x;
var y;
var radius = 50;
var startAngle = 1.1 * Math.PI;
var endAngle = 1.9 * Math.PI;
var counterClockwise = false;

var circles = [];

function handleMouseDown(e) {
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    $("#downlog").html("Down: " + mouseX + " / " + mouseY);
    //check all existing circles to see if we clicked on
    var inCircle = false;
    var tooClose = false;
    for(var i =0;i<circles.length;i++){
        if(circles.length > 0){
            //checks if we clicked in a circle
            if(Math.sqrt((mouseX-circles[i].x)*(mouseX-circles[i].x) + (mouseY-circles[i].y)*(mouseY-circles[i].y)) < radius+5){
                console.log('in circle');
                inCircle = i;
            }
            //checks if we clicked somewhere that would create an over lapping circle
            else if(Math.sqrt((mouseX-circles[i].x)*(mouseX-circles[i].x) + (mouseY-circles[i].y)*(mouseY-circles[i].y)) < radius*2+5){
                console.log('too close');
                tooClose = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if(inCircle !== false){
        //we clicked in a cirlce launch the menu
        console.log('showing menu');
        $('#circle-menu-'+inCircle).css({left:e.clientX,top:e.clientY});
        $('#circle-menu-'+inCircle).show();
    }
    else if(tooClose){
        alert('Cant create new circle, too close to existing one');
        //hide all shown menus
        $('.dropdown').hide();
    }
    else{
        //hide all shown menus
        $('.dropdown').hide();
        console.log('creating new circle');
        //Draw a new circle  
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(mouseX, mouseY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        context.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)';
        //                context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 5;
        context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        context.stroke();

        //build a menu for it
        $('#menus').append($('<div class="dropdown" id="circle-menu-'+circles.length+'"><a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">Dropdown<b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel"><li>Click Me</li></ul></div>'));


        //store that data
        circles.push({x:mouseX,y:mouseY});
    }    
}


$("#myCanvas").mousedown(function (e) {
    handleMouseDown(e);
});
```